# Properly Linking Library

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a `jar` file that is using `pi4j`.

```
sudo java -classpath /opt/pi4j/lib/pi4j-core.jar -jar Test.jar test.Main
```

Problem is I keep getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pi4j/io/gpio/GpioFactory
        at test.Main.main(Main.java:11)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

I don't see why the link isn't being made properly.

Comment: Can you try with `-classpath .:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*'`

Comment: Using this command sudo java -classpath .:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' -jar Test.jar test.Main
Still no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it in command line. But this worked for me:
in IntelliJ, I added the pi4J jar files to my project as modules. I then made an artifact and got IntelliJ to create a jar file for me (with all the dependencies including pi4J). Then I transferred the jar file to the pi and it ran fine.